# SQL Server 2008 PIVOT and JOIN

Tags: sql-server, join, pivot

I have 3 tables with data:

TABLE 1 : **Type**

```
IdType  LibelleType
-------------------
  1         Type1
  2         Type2
```

TABLE 2 : **Procedure**

```
IdProcedur    LibelleProcedure
-------------------------------
    1         Procedure1
    2         Procedure2
```

TABLE 3 : **INFORMATION**

```
IdInfo    IdType    IdProcedure    InfoValue
------------------------------------------------
   1         1          1               11
   2         1          2               12
   3         2          1               21
   4         2          2               22
```

I need a query which will produce this output:

```
         Procedure1   Procedure2
Type1        11           12
Type2        21           22
```

Thank you !

Comment: Can you please do some formatting. Its difficult to understand otherwise.

Comment: I edited the post .. hope can help

Comment: See the answer below. Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check below. The last select does the pivot.(My earlier queries are just to prepare the dataset)

```
        create table Type
(IDType INT,Label VARCHAR(100)
)
create table [PROC]
(IDProc INT, LabelProc varchar(100))
Create table INFO
(IDInfo INT, IDType INT, IDProc INT, INFOValue INT)

insert into Type
values(1,'Type1'),(2,'Type2')

insert into [PROC]
values(1,'Proc1'),(2,'Proc2')

insert into InFO
values(1,1,1,11),(2,1,2,12),(3,2,1,21),(4,2,2,22)

select * from Type
select * from [PROC]
select * from info

declare @labelforprocs varchar(max) = ''
,@sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
select @labelforprocs = CONCAT(@labelforprocs,QUOTENAME(LabelProc),',') from [PROC]
select @labelforprocs = LEFT(@labelforprocs,LEN(@labelforprocs)-1)
SET @sql = 
'select * from
        (
            select T.Label,P.LabelProc,I.INFOValue from INFO I
            INNER JOIN [PROC] P
            ON I.IDPROC = P.IDProc
            INNER JOIN TYPE T
            on T.IDType = I.IDType
        )SRC
        PIVOT
        (MAX(INFOValue)
        FOR LabelProc in (' + @labelforprocs +
        '))piv'
EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer .. please can you help me to select  TYPE and PROCEDURE tables values  dynamically  ?

Comment: Edited the answer to do it dynamically using dynamic sql. Please check.